# AWS API Gateway - keep order of query parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

We have an integration towards a payment provider. To verify their request, they use a hash that is calculated from their query params (the order is important). These are not in alphabetic order (dont know why they did it like that).

Is there any way to make an API-gateway method that preserves the query-parameters "as is"? I understand via the documentation that this is not possible with a proxy method. Is there any other way?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

> In Lambda proxy integration, when a client submits an API request, API
> Gateway passes to the integrated Lambda function an event object,
> except that the order of the request parameters is not preserved